# iPhone/iOS: Determine the default/preferred height of UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm creating a UITextField programmatically (i.e. not in Interface Builder) and I want to know what height value I should use for its frame. Is there an easy way to determine this, or do I have to hard-code a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `UITextField` can be as tall as you want. There's no "preferred" height unless you have text inside of the textfield, in which case you can use `NSString`'s [`-sizeWithFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3a) method:

```
CGSize size = [textField.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
CGRect frame = textField.frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(textField.frame.size.width, size.height);
textField.frame = frame;
```

Comment: But the textField.text does not have any text when I create it, the text is entered by the user. Even if it did have some text, what about the borders and padding of the UITextField around the text itself, don't they need to be taken into consideration when calculating the height?

Comment: @Ramon Yes, you'd factor those in. So if the textfield doesn't have any initial data, then i'm afraid you might have to just stick with a height value and be done with it. This can take a bit of tweaking, but eventually you will figure it out.

Answer (score 16):

Interface builder defaults to 31 for rounded text fields.